# what is the time about nohup command execute in shell?

Tags: shell

I write a shell (CentOS) script command like this:

```
count=`ps -ef | grep ${APP_NAME} | grep -v "grep" | wc -l`
if [[ ${count} -lt 1 ]]; then
  cd ${APP_HOME}
  nohup ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java -Xmx256M -Xms128M -jar -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,suspend=n,server=y,address=5016 ${APP_HOME}/${APP_NAME} >> /dev/null &
  sleep 5
else
  echo "process aready exists!"
  exit 1
fi
```

I execute the script in terminal, the output is:

```
++ ps -ef
++ wc -l
++ grep -v grep
++ grep soa-report-consumer-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
+ count=0
+ [[ 0 -lt 1 ]]
+ cd /data/jenkins/soa-report-consumer
+ sleep 15
+ nohup /opt/dabai/tools/jdk1.8.0_211/bin/java -Xmx256M -Xms128M -jar -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,suspend=n,server=y,address=5016 /data/jenkins/soa-report-consumer/soa-report-consumer-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

The question is: Is the sleep command executed before `nohup` command? Why `echo sleep` command result first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you put the `nohup` command in the background with `&`.
There is no output immediately from the command when you put it in the background as it is running in a separate shell, and your current shell immediately goes to the `sleep` command.  By the time you return from sleep, the `nohup` background process has returned and outputs the value.

If you remove the `&` (and thus run the commands in the same shell) you will see the order changes.